# Pythonic/Numpy way of converting a 1D array into 2D vector array of indexed values

Tags: python, numpy

This is what I currently have:

```py
import numpy as np

data = [0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.5]
vecs = np.reshape([np.arange(len(data)),data], (2, -1)).transpose()
```

```
vecs
array([[ 0.  ,  0.2],
       [ 1.  ,  0.6],
       [ 2.  ,  0.3],
       [ 3.  ,  0.5]])
```

This gives me the correct data as I want it, but it seems complex. Am I missing a trick?

Comment: You could use `np.stack` instead of reshaping and transposing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify with [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) and transpose:

```
data = np.array([0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.5])

np.stack([np.arange(len(data)), data], axis=1)
array([[0. , 0.2],
       [1. , 0.6],
       [2. , 0.3],
       [3. , 0.5]])
```

---

Timings -

```
a = np.random.random(10000)
%timeit np.stack([np.arange(len(a)), a], axis=1) 
# 26.3 µs ± 1.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit np.array([*enumerate(a)])
# 4.51 ms ± 156 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I think you have one extra dimension.

Comment: Yup, just realized :) @arvin

Comment: Might I suggest the use of the `axis` keyword? I think it'll save you from having to do a transpose while also looking neater. Also, you can directly use `range` instead of `np.arange`, though I suppose it's a bit "hacky".

Comment: Thanks for that @arvin Forgot it had that arg. Not hacky, but why not just use np.arange? Numpy has then to cast to float anyways, so we're saving it from some work there

Comment: I mean, if you're looking to save characters I'd use range, though in that case, it'd honestly just be better to enumerate.

Comment: Timings show quite a difference @arvin . And as I say, `range` creates a range of integers, which would then have to be cast to float

Comment: Ah, okay, I was going for more of a code golf approach rather than an efficiency approach, but yeah, using numpy functions is definitely going to be significantly faster.

Comment: @yatu Your answer encouraged me to install IPython / Jupyter.  FYI, timings against my original code at the top proved to be somewhat faster than your solution - eg, with 100 million datapoints (relevant to my workflow) your solution seems to be about 25-30% slower.  I have no idea why what would be.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> np.array([*enumerate(data)])
array([[0. , 0.2],
       [1. , 0.6],
       [2. , 0.3],
       [3. , 0.5]])
```

Comment: Oh *doh*. That's very nice. But is it costly?

Comment: Given a choice between `arange(len(data))` and `enumerate` I think `enumerate` would be much faster.

Comment: It turns out that it's actually quite a bit slower to utilize `enumerate`.

Comment: Yep, saw that. It seems like scaling issue for large arrays.

Comment: Yes, constructing from an iterable of tuples will be slower than just concatenating an np.arange

Comment: Right, I was basing my argument on `range(len(data))` which returns an iterator rather than `arange(len(data))`.